# Add/create modular architecture in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a modular architecture in MVC 6, with several interchangeable modules. Mostly for separation of concerns on grand scale, some modules will be "base modules" (always included). But all should have the same level of decoupling. Now that we have DI and IOC builtin the architecture of this might differ vastly.

I have looked around all over SO and only found MVC 4/5 and MEF solutions, but seeing as the new Startup.cs has changed considerably, and added new methods and best practices, i was wondering if there was a new way to do this.

I did however find the aspnet/Entropy project on GitHub, and they have [Mvc.Modules](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.Modules) package, which might do the trick although this might not be an official thing anytime soon.

**EDIT:**
It seems that the Mvc.Modules mentioned above isn't completely separated yet (controllers specifically), so it only half does the job.

Comment: Hi Jess! Do you have any progress in this task? I have the same task now and I've solved it already in prev version of asp.net using MEF, but now I still don't have any result with this. Maybe we could join forces on this? Thanks!

Comment: I think we should. How do you propose we proceed?

Comment: Please add me in skype: dmitry.sikorsky, I think this is the best way :)

Comment: Hi did you find the way ? Thanks !

Comment: No i went away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MVC 6 is currently under development, it might be a better idea to look at the source code (especially the tests) to find features that you want to use when you cannot locate what you need on the Internet.

MVC 6 has support for DI of both [Controllers](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L35) and [Views](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/DependencyInjection/MvcViewFeaturesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L18). Here are the tests for [Controllers](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.Test/DepenencyInjection/MvcBuilderExtensionsTest.cs#L17) and [Views](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Test/ViewComponents).

Comment: Those links are all 404s now. This answer is not useful.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - I cannot delete the answer now because it is accepted. In hindsight, it should have been a comment. The advice holds for what he was asking at the time it was asked - if there is no documentation, look for unit tests. I can't really change this to answer the question either because "how to architect an architecture" is too broad for Stack Overflow.